# falla onmouseover en el siguiente XHTML por comillas erroneas

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

Al aplicar el siguiente codigo XHTML me falla y no me carga correctamente el directorio de recursos "images", ¿Alguien sabe por que? Creo que se debe al mal uso de comillas simples y dobles, pero es que llevo toda la tarde intentando dar con la combinacion correcta y no lo consigo.

```
<h:link rendered="#{sessionScope.type eq '1'}" id="adminView" outcome="adminView"
        onmouseover="this.src='#{resource['images:home_color.png']}';" 
        onmouseout="this.src='#{resource['images:home.png']}';"
    >
```

Se muestra faltando en el PATH solamente la carpeta /images. En un ovalo rojo el path erroneo y en un ovalo verde los paths incorrectos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.
Salu2.
Chema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución de esta manera:

```
<h:link rendered="#{sessionScope.type eq '1'}" id="adminView" outcome="adminView">
            <h:graphicImage border="0" title="Home" alt="Home" url="#{resource['images:home.png']}"
                onmouseover="this.src='#{resource['images:home_color.png']}';"
                onmouseout="this.src='#{resource['images:home.png']}';"
            />
        </h:link>
```